# How do I arrive at this Taylor series expansion for the given function?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, finite-differences

This is taken from my textbook on numerical analysis/scientific computing:

[image]

I don't quite understand the explanations here and was hoping someone could help break this down for me. I am able to get the first two terms by simply rearranging the given approximation:

$f(x+h) = h*f'(x) + f(x) = f(x) + f'(x)h$

But the third term, and the explanation in the text that follows, seems to appear out of nowhere.

From Taylor series, I recognize it as the natural third term that would arise in approximating a function, but what's with the theta and the stuff about $M$?

Comment: It’s the remainder term

Comment: Taylor's theorem includes an explicit expression for the remainder. If you read about Taylor's theorem with remainder you'll see where the remainder term $f''(\theta) h^2/2$ comes from.

Comment: By the way, the book should say "for a **twice** differentiable function $f$". They implicitly assume that $f$ is twice differentiable when they write $f''$, but it's good to be explicit about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that 
$$f(x+h) \simeq h*f'(x) + f(x) = f(x) + f'(x)h$$
is an approximation, not an equality.

The error of the estimate can be written explicitely by the [Lagrange Remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html), a more general version of the Mean Value Theorem. This result is exactly what they use here.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder: $$f(x+h)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\frac{h^j}{j!}f^{(j)}(x)+\frac{h^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\theta),$$ where $\theta$ is between $x$ and $x+h$ (for a sufficiently regular function).